# Boundedness of the derivative of a function satisfying the conditions of Rolle's Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ on $[a,b]$ be a differentiable function such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Does it follow that $\sup_{x\in[a,b]} f'(x) < \infty$?

The assertion in question was used in the solution to a certain problem and I'm wondering whether it is obvious. I can't seem to find a way to justify it; $f'$ has intermediate value property but I don't see how boundedness might follow from this.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how the derivative could be unbounded high and still have the function come back to where it starts,  but not seeing the obvious proof offhand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{2}\cos(1/x^{2})$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Now find a bump function $\varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}$ such that $\varphi(x)=1$ on a neighborhood of $0$.

Look at the function $f\cdot\varphi$, so it vanishes on sufficiently large $|x|\geq M$.

But if we look at $(f\cdot\varphi)'(x)$ around $0$, it is simply $f'(x)$, and we compute that $f'(x)=2x\cos(1/x^{2})+(2/x)\sin(1/x^{2})$.

Let $x_{n}=1/\sqrt{2n\pi+\pi/4}$ and we see that $f'(x_{n})\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Is the bump function 1 on neighborhood of 0 or is it the identity?

Comment: The constant $1$ on a neighborhood of $0$. The philosophy is that, the multiplication $f\cdot\varphi$ on a neighborhood of $0$ is simply the $f$.

Comment: Oh, i read it as composition of functions

Comment: Just realize that $f(-1/\sqrt{\pi/2})=f(1/\sqrt{\pi/2})=0$, so the $f$ is already what you need for the counterexample.

Comment: You could simplify by letting $\phi(x)=(1+x).$